# How to disable custom controller Action on header click of webGrid?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following tab links which will change the data displayed in the webgrid as below,

[jqueryImageSnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3axxV.jpg)

following the cshtml file for the same,

```
 <div class="top-grid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-2">

        <p>
            <a href="#" id="EligiblePayLink">ELIGIBLE FOR EARLY PAY</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <h2>@Model.SupplierInitialPage.PendingInvoicesCount</h2>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="PendingApprovalLink">PENDING APPROVAL</a></p>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
</div>
 <div class="bottom-grid" id="InvoiceGridContents">

</div>
```

Below is the partial view with its controller class,

```
 WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.EligiblePayInvoices, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: recCount);
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

        @grid.GetHtml(

                 tableStyle: "table", // applying style on grid

        fillEmptyRows: true,
    //show empty row when there is only one record on page to it will display all empty rows there.       
        headerStyle: "header", //applying style.

        footerStyle: "grid-footer", //applying style.

        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, //paging to grid 
        firstText: "<< First",
        previousText: "< Prev",
        nextText: "Next >",
        lastText: "Last >>",



        columns: new[]  // colums in grid
        {
            grid.Column(header:"DATE SUBMITTED",columnName: "DateSubmitted",style: "width-250px"), //the model fields to display
            grid.Column(header:"INVOICE #",columnName: "InvoiceNumber",style: "width-250px"),
            grid.Column(header:"INVOICE TITLE",columnName: "InvoiceTitle",style: "width-250px"),                
            grid.Column(header:"AMOUNT",columnName:"InvoiceAmount",style: "width-250px"),
            grid.Column(header:"PO#",columnName: "PONumber",style: "width-250px"),                
            grid.Column(header:"STATUS",columnName:"Status",format: item => Html.Raw(item.Status),style: "width-250px")
       })
```

And now the controller class,

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowInvoiceGrid(int Id = 1)
    {
        var type = (PayInvoiceStatusType)Id;
        PayInvoiceViewModel _invoiceModel = objHelper.GetStreamPaySession(Session);
        if (_invoiceModel != null) 
            _invoiceModel = UpdatePayInvoiceViewModel(type);
        else
            _invoiceModel = CreateInitialPayInvoiceViewModel(type);

        return PartialView("_InvoiceGrid", _invoiceModel);
    }
```

The problem is, when i click on the header of the webgrid, its triggering the custom controller action method and returning me only the grid partial view not the full page. Is there any idea?